# Magento 2 How To Preview Adminhtml Email template in Frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, frontend, email-templates

I'm trying to preview email adminhtml template to front-end but its not working, I have tried below code.

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend'  template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preview your email template created from the backend of Magento 2.

Please navigate to Marketing>Email Templates

I hope this will help you.

For you guys out there Just correct me if I'm wrong

Thanks

[image]

Comment: hai,  i want to preview email template  in front end not backend preview. How can call preview in frontend block or any other solution is there

Comment: Hello Not sure. but please do try reading this one: https://gordonlesti.com/magento-2-email-template-block-directives/

Comment: Hai Maze, thanks for your response , itz possible to do that view front end email template   preview @ MazeStricks

Comment: Hello @KamalakannanRavichandran you're welcome. I think it is possible

Comment: Hai @ MazeStricks , Let me know how to do give any idea or already u did it plz shared your code